# javascript move list item on window resize

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, window-resize

I have a list of items (displayed horizontally) and a dropdown list. I'm trying to understand how can I move items from the horizontal list to the dropdown list on window resize. Basically I have just one row where I can fit my items. If it doesn't fit (adding list items width) I want to put them in a dropdown list. I'm using angularjs.

```html
<div class="name-list">
  <ul class="horizontal">
    <li><a href="#">item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">item 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">item 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="dropdown more-names">
  <button>More</button>
  <ul class="dropdown">
    <li><a href="#">item 4</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">item 5</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">item 6</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Just have the same content inside the dropdown as well and show//hide using media queries.

Comment: Thanks - that's a good idea. However I need to be able to calculate the width of the horizontal items ? Is this possible?

Comment: You don't have to calculate the width, just define few media queries for eg, one for mobile size, one for tablet size, one for desktop and then decide at which size your horizontal items go into the dropdown and write the css rule for show/hide in the media query for that size... That's how even major UI frameworks does it.

Comment: But if I add the class to all the items, I'll have all of them moving from the horizontal list to the dropdown. What I need is to move some of them.

Comment: Why can't you add a special class to the items you want to move? There is no limit on the number of classes you can add

Comment: Understand what you are saying. Yes I can add a special class. But to set that class to the specific item, I need first to know the sum of the li items right? lets say my window is 500px and I have 5 items of 200px each... In this case I want to show the first two horizontally and the other three on a dropdown. However those items might have different widths so if my li items now have 150 each I want to show the first three horizontally and the other two on a dropdown. So I reckon the bit that I'm still missing is how to get the width of the li items and then assign the classes.

Comment: You can't handle all the resolutions like `499px`, `500px`, `501px` and so on.  Instead you say if window is smaller than 500px everything goes to dropdown. If it's `500-1000px`  2 items goes to dropdown and above that everything is horizontal etc. Like I already mentioned you need to design your application for few common resolutions. Look into how responsive design in done using famous ui frameworks like bootstrap. You need to do some research and understand responsive, adaptive design that is used nowadays. I can't add the entire idea in a comment or an answer. It's more than that.

Answer (score 1):

Just set up a $watch in your controller:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
    return $window.innerWidth;
}, function(value) {
    console.log('window inner width is now', value);
    yourFunctionToMoveListItem();
});
```

You should use the `$window` service, instead of javascript `window`, since it's a bit safer... Quoting from the docs:

> While window is globally available in JavaScript, it causes
>   testability problems, because it is a global variable. In angular we
>   always refer to it through the $window service, so it may be
>   overridden, removed or mocked for testing.

Comment: ...while re sizing this is probably going to trigger hundreds of times. It's better to do responsive designing than doing stuff like this...

Comment: You're probably right... Mine is just an answer to a question... :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use css media queries to show/hide html element when window resized. For example like this

```
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    .myClass {
        width: 100px;
    }
}
```

Because in code snippet you can't change page size of demo and see result, i create my example in **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lrgr3st/)**.

Comment: Nice example. However this will work for all of the items. I need to push some items to the dropdown - not all the items. So the first list will still have items visible (that can fit in one horizontal line) and the remaining need to go to the dropdown.